# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing big local array

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I am confused about a crash in code I haven't touched recently and it worked before. (It wasn't called during my tests in the last two weeks and I worked on other parts of the project.) I narrowed it down to the code below.

I am creating a local array to do some operations on a height map. I can't explain why it is crashing even though the code is very simple. The only issue I can see is the size of the array but I am also using bigger data structures and it has worked fine before.

Now it is crashing in the simulator and on the iPhone. The crash always happens when i reaches 124. I can place the code from below anywhere in my project, it is always the same value for i when it crashes.

```
{
    const int tsize=512;
    double h[tsize][tsize]; //height map
    h[500][500]=1.0f;
    h[250][1]=1.0f; // working fine
    for(int i=0;i<tsize;i+=1){
        h[i][1]=0.0f;   // always crashing at i=124

    }
}
```

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x70000763e258)

- Of course I tried to clean the build folder.
- I also tried to create the array using malloc and accessing it with pointers but it leads to the same crash.

When I play around with the `tsize` value and make it a little bit bigger, the crash already happens when the method is called which contains this code.

Comment: The code seems ok to me. I pasted it in a new project and it runs smoothly up to i=511

Comment: There must be a fault somewhere else in the project but what makes me nuts is that the crash always happens at i=124, whether the code is inserted in the main update loop, in a random function, in an async function call or a block executed by a button press. The scope is so small, what could go wrong?

Comment: I have no idea. What I am sure about is the fact that the code you provided runs correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you are exceeding the maximum stack size and, when that happens, the behavior is largely undefined and will lead to weird crashes.

The main thread's stack size is larger than secondary threads, by the way.

In general, you should never use any significant amount of memory on the stack.   And 512 * 512 * sizeof(double) is a *huge* amount of memory to pull from the stack!

Comment: You are right, it was the stack. The heap version using malloc is working fine. (I made a mistake when I tried it first.) This code is working fine:
  {
  const int tsize=512;
  double *h=malloc(tsize*tsize*sizeof(double));
  h[tsize*500+500]=1.0f;
  h[tsize*250+1]=1.0f;
  for(int i=0;i<tsize;i+=1){
   h[tsize*i+1]=0.0f;
  }
  free(h);
 }